# check chai as promised on multiple properties object

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai-as-promised

hello I have a method which returns me data along with URL , so return object has url and body as two properties.

```
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject)
    {
      request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if(error)
              reject(error);
          else
          {
              if(response.statusCode ==200)
                    resolve( { "url" :url , "body" : body});
                else
                    reject("error while getting response from " + url);
          }
      });

    });
```

How should I test this in Chai- as promised

it works for 1 property.

```
it("get data from correct url", function(){
   return expect (httphelper.getWebPageContent(config.WebUrl))
   .to.eventually.have.property('url')
});
```

if I include other property it searches inside previous property.

```
it("get data from correct url", function(){
   return expect (httphelper.getWebPageContent(config.WebUrl))
   .to.eventually.have.property('url')
   .and.to.have.property('body')
});
```

AssertionError: expected 'http://www.jsondiff.com/' to have property 'body'

where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Does this work without promises (i.e. without the `eventually`) in plain Chai?

Comment: Please accept the proposed answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

Create an object with the expected properties :

```
const expected = {
    url: "expected url",
    body: "expected body"
};
```

Then ensure the result include this properties with :

```
return expect(httphelper.getWebPageContent(config.WebUrl))
.fulfilled.and.eventually.include(expected);
```

Answer (score 1):

First on your problem; the check for `body` happens on the object `url`, not on the original object (the chaining is like jQuery chaining), and as the error message says, the string `http://www.jsondiff.com/` does not have a property of `body`.

Given that, one solution would be to get the returned object and then do two separate checks:

```
it('get data from correct url', async () => {
  const res = await httphelper.getWebPageContent(config.WebUrl));

  expect(res).to.have.property('url');
  expect(res).to.have.property('body');
});
```

or if you want to stick with `chai-as-promised`:

```
it('get data from correct url', async () => {
  const res = httphelper.getWebPageContent(config.WebUrl));

  expect(res).to.be.fulfilled
  .then(() => {
    expect(res).to.have.property('url');
    expect(res).to.have.property('body');
  });
});
```

Another solution would be to grab the object's *keys* and then use the `members()` function to see if the list contains your properties:

```
it('get data from correct url', async () => {
  const res = await httphelper.getWebPageContent(config.WebUrl));

  expect(Object.keys(res)).to.have.members(['url', 'body']);
});
```