# chai as promise call function once

Tags: chai, chai-as-promised

How can I do this with chai-as-promised:

Currently I am using chai expect:

```
return User.auth(data).then(function(usr){
  expect(usr).to.have.property('user', 'alvin');
  expect(usr).to.have.property('email', 'alvin@l.com');
});
```

for chai-as-promisied, I can call mulutiple call but I would like to call once:

```
return User.auth(data).should.eventually.have.property('');
return User.auth(data).should.eventually.have.property('');
```

---

The solution:

```
it('should return user', function(){
            this.timeout(15000);            
            let data = { req: {
                email: 'alvin@l.com'
            }};

            let expected = {
                email: 'alvin@l.com'
            };

            return 
 User.auth(data).should.be.fulfilled.and.eventually.include(expected);
        });
```

Comment: [Duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46064455/check-chai-as-promised-on-multiple-properties-object/46078723#46078723). It works also with should

Comment: @Troopers too bad your answer there hasn't been accepted, so I can't close this one as being a duplicate :(

Comment: Run this, return User.auth(data).should.be.fulfilled.and.eventually.include(expected); I got Error: Timeout of 15000ms exceeded.

Comment: @Alvin can you post the full (updated) test (`it(...)`)

Comment: @robertklep updated y question.

Comment: @robertklep, nevermind I solved the problem.